# How the "References" field in MIME email messages are used in practice?

Tags: email, gmail, mime, email-client, yahoo-mail

Per [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046):

> The inclusion of a "References" field in the headers of the second and subsequent pieces of a fragmented message that references the Message-Id on the previous piece may be of benefit to mail readers that understand and track references.  However, the generation of such "References" fields is entirely optional.

I see this. It does not explicitly mention how it is usually used in practice. Does anybody have a summary of common email clients and online email service providers (e.g., Gmail) on how this is implemented in practice?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not generally used in practice.  In the 25+ years that I've been online, I've never once seen a fragmented message spanning multiple emails.  And most email providers have a cap on email sizes anyway, making fragmentation even less likely.

Comment: I know that it is not used for fragmentation of the same message. I observe that it has been used to reference previous emails (not just the one being replied to directly) in the same thread. That is why I want to know how it is used in practice. People who are familiar with email clients might be in a better position to answer.